# Get facebook profile picture always return silhouette

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Everyone knows `https://graph.facebook.com/[facebook_id]/picture?redirect=false` will retrieve the URL of the profile picture.

I've tried it on browsers, NestJS back end, etc.

I don't know why it turns into a silhouette picture but when I provided the access_token the URL was changed to `https://platform-lookaside.fbsbx.com/....` that not return the silhouette anymore. This gives me the profile picture but it is always downloaded rather than just displayed. Moreover, the URL from my latest approach is a signed URL and it has expiration time but I need a static URL for the profile picture.

Did anyone have an idea for this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs

> GET /{user-id}/picture requests made by apps in Development mode using either (1) a Client access token or (2) tokenless requests on an App-Scoped User ID will receive a silhouette image instead of the app user's profile image in response.

See full documentation
[here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/non-versioned-changes/sep-16-2020/)

Answer (score -2):

It's solved!

Just use the url directly in src of img